# Relaxation of the set given by knapsack constraints

Tags: linear-programming, relaxations

A set $\mathcal{A}$ is the relaxation of another set $\mathcal{B}$, if $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$.

I have a set of points defined as

$$
\mathcal{X} = \{x \in \mathcal{Z}^n_{+}: w^{\top}x \leq b \}
$$
where $\mathcal{Z}^n_+$ is the n-dimensional 0-1 vectors and $w \in \Re^n_+$ and $b \in \Re_+$.

I read that one possible relaxation of the above set is 
$$
\mathcal{X} = \{x \in \mathcal{Z}^n_{+}: \lfloor w\rfloor ^{\top}x \leq \lfloor b\rfloor \}
$$

where $\lfloor \rfloor$ represents the floor function.

It is very counter-intuitive to me.  $w^\top x \leq b$ represents a half space with left or lower space of the hyperplane defined by $w^\top x = b$. By taking the floor function, we are in fact moving the hyperplane lower and shrinking the size of the set.

Can anyone explain to me why the floor function terms represent a relaxed set ?

Comment: [or.se] is also a good place for questions on [tag:linear-programming].

Comment: Answered here https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/111413/relaxation-of-the-knapsack-constraints